# Bootstrap 3 inline group input and select button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are some kind of options for aligning form inline and to align dropdown button with input fields and some other variations, even with select button but that is only with small select buttons like dropdown button like 40px width.

My problem is that i am trying to make search bar with input and long select dropdown something like aliexpress have.

[image]

So far i have tried various style hacks on my own but none of them works well in aligning button with input field responsively, i have also googled but nothing really that works.

I only got it working like this
[image]

I am trying to join search input and categories like input group buttons.

Anyone have any idea or hidden code that i couldn't find?

Comment: I actually expected some negativity on this question because i really don't know how to ask it better, i added a few screenshots if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" style="width: 300px; margin-right: 35px, border: 1px solid black; background-color: #e5e5e5;" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
                                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                                <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

also it has css

```
    body {
    padding: 60px 0px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px !important;
    max-height: 270px;
}
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    border-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    padding: 16px 12px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
    box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        padding-top: 0px !important;
        padding-right: 38px !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
        width: 38px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
        padding: 15px 12px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
        padding: 25px 12px;
        font-size: 18pt;
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
        display: table-cell;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

and small js file

```
    $(function () {
    // Remove Search if user Resets Form or hits Escape!
    $('body, .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"]').on('click keyup', function(event) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
        if (event.which == 27 && $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]').hasClass('active') ||
            $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') == 'reset') {
            closeSearch();
        }
    });

    function closeSearch() {
        var $form = $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active')
        $form.find('input').val('');
        $form.removeClass('active');
    }

    // Show Search if form is not active // event.preventDefault() is important, this prevents the form from submitting
    $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]:not(.active) button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
            $input = $form.find('input');
        $form.addClass('active');
        $input.focus();

    });
    // ONLY FOR DEMO // Please use $('form').submit(function(event)) to track from submission
    // if your form is ajax remember to call `closeSearch()` to close the search container
    $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
            $input = $form.find('input');
        $('#showSearchTerm').text($input.val());
        closeSearch()
    });
});
```